# How to count no. of rows between time intervals(hourly) in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My data has various columns including a date and a time column. The data is stretched across three months. I need to count no. of rows in a particular hour irrespective of the date. So that would mean getting the count of rows in 00:00 to 01:00 window and similarly for the rest 23 hours. How do I do that? Overall I will have 24 rows with their counts.
Here is my data:

```
>>>df[["date","time"]]

    date    time
0   2006-11-10  00:01:21
1   2006-11-10  00:02:26
2   2006-11-10  00:02:38
3   2006-11-10  00:05:38
4   2006-11-10  00:05:38
```

Output should be like:

```
00:00-00:59 SomeCount
```

Both are object types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think simpliest is convert both columns to datetimes and count hours by [`Series.dt.hour`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.hour.html) with [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
out = pd.to_datetime(df["date"] + ' ' + df["time"]).dt.hour.value_counts().sort_index()
```

Or if need your format use [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) with [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
s = pd.to_datetime(df["date"] + ' ' + df["time"]).dt.strftime('%H:00-%H:59')
print (s)
0    00:00-00:59
1    00:00-00:59
2    00:00-00:59
3    00:00-00:59
4    00:00-00:59
dtype: object

out = s.groupby(s, sort=False).size()
print (out)

00:00-00:59    5
dtype: int64
```

Last for DataFrame use:

```
df = out.rename_axis('times').reset_index(name='count')
```

Comment: Is `Groupby.size` better than `value_counts` in the second case

Comment: @MustafaAydın - Hard question, maybe `value_counts` should be faster, but main difference is `value_counts` counts by default.

Answer (score 1):

You can split the time string with the delimiter `:`. Then create an another column `hour` for hour. Then use `groupby()` to group them on the basis of new column `hour`. You can now store the data in a new series or dataframe to get the desired output

Answer (score 1):

- `groupby()` the hour
- then build DF that has values you want
- cleanup indexes and column names

```
import io
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""    date    time
0   2006-11-10  00:01:21
1   2006-11-10  00:02:26
2   2006-11-10  00:02:38
3   2006-11-10  00:05:38
4   2006-11-10  02:05:38"""), sep="\s\s+", engine="python")

dfc = (df.groupby(pd.to_datetime(df.time).dt.hour)
 .apply(lambda d: pd.DataFrame({"count":[len(d)]}, 
                               index=[pd.to_datetime(d["time"]).min().strftime("%H:%M")
                                      +"-"+pd.to_datetime(d["time"]).max().strftime("%H:%M")]))
 .reset_index()
 .drop(columns=["time"])
 .rename(columns={"level_1":"time"})
)
```

|  | time | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 00:01-00:05 | 4 |
| 1 | 02:05-02:05 | 1 |

Answer (score 1):

My solution generates row counts for **all** 24 hours, with *0* for hours "absent"
in the source DataFrame.

To show a more instructive example, I defined the source DataFrame containing
rows from several hours:

```
         date      time
0  2006-11-10  01:21:00
1  2006-11-10  02:26:00
2  2006-11-10  02:38:00
3  2006-11-10  05:38:00
4  2006-11-10  05:38:00
5  2006-11-11  05:43:00
6  2006-11-11  05:51:00
```

Note that last 2 rows are from different date, but as you want grouping by
**hour only**, they will be counted in the same group as previous 2 rows
(hour *5*).

The first step is to create a *Series* containing almost what you want:

```
wrk = df.groupby(pd.to_datetime(df.time).dt.hour).apply(
    lambda grp: grp.index.size).reindex(range(24), fill_value=0)
```

The initial part of *wrk* is:

```
time
0     0
1     1
2     2
3     0
4     0
5     4
6     0
7     0
```

The left column (the index) contains hour as an **integer** and the
right column is the count - how many rows are in this hour.

The only thing to do is to reformat the index to your desired format:

```
wrk.index = wrk.index.map(lambda h: f'{h:02}:00-{h:02}:59')
```

The result (initial part only) is:

```
time
00:00-00:59    0
01:00-01:59    1
02:00-02:59    2
03:00-03:59    0
04:00-04:59    0
05:00-05:59    4
06:00-06:59    0
07:00-07:59    0
```

But if you want to get counts **only** for hours present in your source
data, then drop `.reindex(…)` from the above code.

Then your (full) result, for the above DataFrame will be:

```
time
01:00-01:59    1
02:00-02:59    2
05:00-05:59    4
dtype: int64
```